# How do I get the result shape of a user defined table valued function in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

By "result shape" I mean a list of column names and data types returned by the function. With a stored procedure I can use `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object`:

```
SELECT name, system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object
(
  OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[MyProcedureName]'), 
  NULL
);
```

But if I call that system function with the name of a table valued function, I just get null.

Is there any way to do the same for a table valued function?

Comment: Should be in sys.columns - just like a view or table. I will note that you write "user defined table valued function" but your example implies "stored procedure".

Answer (score 0):

**A table function cannot be used in that context, because it has no inherent "result", it is in essence a parameterized view.**

`sys.columns` has all the details you need

```sql
SELECT c.name, t.name as system_type_name
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.types t ON t.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[MyProcedureName]');
```

---

Another option: you could use `dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` on a batch instead.

Note that you need to fill in parameters if necessary. They could just be `default`.

```sql
SELECT name, system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set
(
  'select * from [dbo].[MyProcedureName]()', 
  NULL,
  1
);
-- for parameters:
SELECT name, system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set
(
  'select * from [dbo].[MyProcedureName2](default, default)', 
  NULL,
  1
);
```

If you don't know how many parameters, you can use a little bit of dynamic SQL:

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@functionName) + N'(' +
  (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(N'DEFAULT', N',')
    FROM sys.parameters p
    WHERE p.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@functionName)
  ) + N')';

SELECT name, system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set
(
  @sql, 
  NULL,
  1
);
```

Comment: Hmm... But that requires me to actually call the stored procedure or function. Some of these might have side effects that I don't want to happen just for checking the result set, plus then I'd need to come up with dummy values to put in for each parameter.

Comment: `dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` does not actually execute anything, it just returns what it thinks is the first resultset. You can pass `null` for every parameter, except TVPs, so maybe change it to `default`

Comment: @ekolis Looks like you could just use `sys.columns` and `sys.types` anyway